# React - how to make sure flex-item bottom spacing is on the same level

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

This is the UI
[image]

I want to make sure the "Click Me" buttons of all items always remain the same margin/padding bottom(e.g. 24px).

In my image, the "Click Me" buttons in items 2 and 3 are incorrect, which should be 24px bottom spacing.

How can I fix it?

App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import React from "react";
import { Card, Col as AntdCol, Row as AntdRow, Typography } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";

const { Meta } = Card;
const { Link, Text } = Typography;

const CardRow = styled(AntdRow)`
  margin-bottom: 16px;
`;

const CardMeta = styled(Meta)`
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const StyledCard = styled(Card)`
  .ant-card-cover img {
    aspect-ratio: 12/10;
  }
  .ant-card-meta-description {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  height: 100%;
`;

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 16px;
`;

const StyledLinkText = styled(Text)`
  white-space: nowrap;
`;

const MyCard = ({ title, description, imgSrc, url }: any) => (
  <StyledCard cover={<img src={imgSrc} alt="134" />}>
    <CardMeta title={title} description={description} />
    <StyledLink href={url ? url : "#"} target="_blank">
      <StyledLinkText>Click Me</StyledLinkText>
    </StyledLink>
  </StyledCard>
);

export default function App() {
  const objects = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "title 1",
      description: `Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.`,
      imageSrc: "src-1",
      url: "url 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "title 2",
      description: "description 2",
      imageSrc: "src-2",
      url: "url 2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "title 3",
      description: "description 3",
      imageSrc: "src-3",
      url: "url 3"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <CardRow gutter={[16, 16]} justify={"space-between"}>
      {objects.map((news, i) => (
        <AntdCol key={i} xs={{ span: 8, offset: 0 }}>
          <MyCard {...news} />
        </AntdCol>
      ))}
    </CardRow>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-30lhof

Comment: The codesandbox isn't working for me but try: margin-top: auto; and margin-bottom:"24px"; on the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These CSS rules solve your problem.Just replace them:

[image: sandbox screen shot]

```
const CardMeta = styled(Meta)`
  justify-content: space-between;
flex:1;
`;

const StyledCard = styled(Card)`
  .ant-card-body{
    flex:1;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  .ant-card-cover img {
    aspect-ratio: 12/10;
  }
  .ant-card-meta-description {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  height: 100%;
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set `flex:1` to your description element. it causes the description to contain the entire space and then the click me `button` goes as bottom as it can( it respects the `margin-bottom`).

Comment: not working on my example, since antd is a bit tricky

Answer (score 1):

If you will give min-height of 70px to
.ant-card-meta-description div

your body div will stay min height of 70px no matter how much text it has.
As you have text overflow: ellipsis after 3 lines text will look ok

Comment: This is on the right track. I misunderstood the question. I would use flex on the child to ensure the button is aligned to the bottom vs min-height. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, try to replace `StyledCard` variable with below.

```
const StyledCard = styled(Card)`
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .ant-card-cover img {
    aspect-ratio: 12/10;
  }
  .ant-card-body {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .ant-card-body::before,
  .ant-card-body::after {
    content: none;
  }
  .ant-card-meta-description {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
`;
```